# WinDbg: Dump indicates CLR version that is used nowhere

Tags: windbg, dump, sos

I am analyzing a memory dump of an IIS worker process running on a Windows Server 2008 on my Windows 8 workstation. The dump is a mini dump taken using task manager.

The .Net Framework versions on server and workstation differ:

- Workstation: 4.0.30319.18046
- Server where the dump was taken: 4.0.30319.296

I copied sos.dll and mscordacwks.dll from the server to my workstation in a dedicated directory, then opened the dump in WinDbg.

Symbol File Path:  SRV*c:\dev\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

Then I load the sos.dll copied from the server:

```
0:000> .load D:\temp\dumps\sos.dll
```

This allows me to list the threads using !threads or watch stacks using !clrstack.

But when using !pe or !clrstack, I get a version mismatch warning:

```
0:000> !pe
The version of SOS does not match the version of CLR you are debugging.  Please
load the matching version of SOS for the version of CLR you are debugging.
CLR Version: 4.0.30319.1
SOS Version: 4.0.30319.296
The current thread is unmanaged
```

While I could see the stacks that interested me, I'm confused about the CLR Version in the warning: Where does this version come from?

The dump indicates version 4.0.30319.1 when I execute

```
lmv m clr
```

But 4.0.30319.1 is used nowhere in this case, neither on server nor workstation. 
Or am I missing something?

Additionally, WinDbg loads the symbol files for mscordacwks_AMD64_AMD64_4.0.30319.01.dll to my symbols directory.

Output of .cordll:

```
0:000> .cordll -ve -u -l
CLRDLL: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscordacwks.dll:4.0.30319.18046 f:8
doesn't match desired version 4.0.30319.01 f:8
CLRDLL: Loaded DLL c:\dev\symbols\mscordacwks_AMD64_AMD64_4.0.30319.01.dll\4BA21EEB965000\mscordacwks_AMD64_AMD64_4.0.30319.01.dll
CLR DLL status: Loaded DLL c:\dev\symbols\mscordacwks_AMD64_AMD64_4.0.30319.01.dll\4BA21EEB965000\mscordacwks_AMD64_AM D64_4.0.30319.01.dll
```

I also tried to copy clr.dll from the server to my workstation and load the runtime using .cordll, but without success:

```
0:000> .cordll -u -lp D:\temp\dumps
CLRDLL: D:\temp\dumps\mscordacwks.dll:4.0.30319.296 f:8
doesn't match desired version 4.0.30319.01 f:8
CLRDLL: Unable to get version info for 'D:\temp\dumps\mscordacwks_AMD64_AMD64_4.0.30319.01.dll', Win32 error 0n87
CLRDLL: ERROR: Unable to load DLL D:\temp\dumps\mscordacwks_AMD64_AMD64_4.0.30319.01.dll, Win32 error 0n87
CLR DLL status: ERROR: Unable to load DLL D:\temp\dumps\mscordacwks_AMD64_AMD64_4.0.30319.01.dll, Win32 error 0n87
```

Can anyone shed some light on this versioning issue? Is it somehow related to the type of dump used?

Comment: How did you determine this version number: Server where the dump was taken: 4.0.30319.296? Did you do it at the same time when the dump was created? If you did it later, maybe an update was installed, so your dump has CLR 4...1 but in the meanwhile .NET was updated to 4...296. I would believe the information of the dump, which means you need to get SOS 4...1 from somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Steps that worked for me (assuming process was 64 bit):

1. Copy C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\SOS.dll from server machine to local directory on your dev machine.
2. Copy C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscordacwks.dll to the same directory where you copied sos.dll into. Then rename it to mscordacwks_AMD64_AMD64_4.0.30319.01.dll.
3. Load the copied version of sos.dll -- mscordacrwks will be loaded automatically.

In more details, the procedure is described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/salvapatuel/archive/2010/03/09/how-to-configure-windbg-to-run-other-versions-of-the-net.aspx?Redirected=true.